# What is this insect in this picture?

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

I recently found this insect  near our veranda wall. **What insect is this ?**
Is it poisonous?

[image]

As you can see, it has multiple legs fine as hair, but it is not like a common millipede or centipede.
I searched for this insect by reverse Google image search without result.

Location: Kolkata, India

Nature: fast-moving, aggressive.

Unlike earthworms, this insect loves basking in sunlight.

Comment: It looks like Scutigera coleoptrata. From Wikipedia: Bites are uncommon, and the forcipules of house centipedes are not strong enough to easily penetrate human skin. Bites are similar to a bee's sting, with its venom causing redness and mild to severe swelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's [Scutigera coleoptrata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scutigera_coleoptrata).

[image]

[Source of the image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Scutigera_coleoptrata.JPG).

Comment: About [copy righted image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253305/338088). Also if an image is not your own work it's source needs to be mentioned.

Comment: While using copyrighted image on SE it is advisable (as in the link)  that the copy right allows sharing image as being done, if not it is right to replace it with one that allows.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh, I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a house centipede, which are harmless to people.  The ones I encounter love cool, dark, damp places like the basement, and move lightning fast.  They are also prone to dropping off legs when you try to catch them.

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE. Please add a picture and provide references. You can visit the [help center](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help) for more details about how this site works.